# Is there a way to specify the IKEv2 security association parameters for Personal VPN?

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension

I'm trying to set up a [Personal VPN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension#3150427) in my application.

The Apple docs state that a personal VPN configuration uses one of the built-in VPN protocols (IKEv2 in my case).

The basic configuration is fairly straightforward, however, when specifying the settings for the IKEv2 configuration, the official documentation seems to lack some information/some parts are not fully documented.

The `NEVPNProtocolIKEv2` class has two getters, `ikeSecurityAssociationParameters` and `childSecurityAssociationParameters`. Good to know that I can get that data, but is there a way to set it? Seems like by default, iOS proposes the following algorithms to establish an IKE SA: `IKE:3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024`.

Since 3DES is considered a weak encryption algorithm, SHA1 being an outdated hash function and 1024b Dh-group is considered deprecated as well, I'd like to change certain parameters accordingly.

My question: is that possible with a personal VPN or do I have to move to a Packet Tunnel Provider and use my "custom" VPN protocol implementation? Also, why does Apple set such weak parameters by default?

Comment: Hey, would you be so kind and leave a comment when downvoting? What's missing? What's wrong? If you bother to downvote, please also bother to leave a comment!

Comment: Have you tried setting different algorithms? What happened?  You don't set a new value of `ikeSecurityAssociationParameters` - You simply change the properties of the existing object that is referred to by that property.

Comment: Darn, stupid me, sorry, I haven’t dealt with OOP in a while, just C... Indeedthen, this question deserves a downvote, haha. Thanks @Paulw11

Comment: I didn't downvote by the way.  It wasn't that bad a question - The solution isn't obvious from the Apple documentation

Comment: Haha, you’re funny, well, that’s right

Comment: The chances are that if you have this question, then others will too - that is the point of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ikeSecurityAssociationParameters` and `childSecurityAssociationParameters` properties are get-only but you can modify the properties of the objects referred to by these properties before you establish your connection:

```
let protocol = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
protocol.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = .algorithmAES256GCM
```